# How to update $scope object without reload of page?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, dictionary

Howdie do,

So I'm returning an dictionary from Python that is then jsonify'ed before passing it to angular.

For example, this is the dictionary that I'm returning from my Python:

```
the_dict = {"success": False, excludedPkgs: ['12345', '45678'], message:'Failed to depart pkgs'}

return jsonfiy(the_dict)
```

This dictionary contains a status, a list of excluded packages and an error message.

The result is returned to angular via a dataFactory function and updates the $sessionStorage if the status is False

```
departedFromPackages: function(ids, user_id){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: urlBase + 'depart/pkg/',
          data: {'order_id': ids, 'user': user_id}
        }).then(function(res){
         if (res.data.success == false) {
            $storage.failedPkgs = res.data.excludedPkgs;
         }

        });
      }
```

Now in my Packages controller, I automatically get the $storage.failedPkgs and setup a $scope.$watchCollection, what I hoped would automatically show the updated values in the console:

Packages Controller

```
$scope.failedPkgs = dataFactory.getFailedPkgs();

    $scope.$watchCollection('failedPkgs', function (newVal, oldVal){
        console.log(newVal, oldVal)
    });
```

Now, the issue is that the console initially shows undefined when you load the packages.html screen, which makes sense. The user has to click a departed button that will attempt to depart a package which basically means taking the package information and injecting it into a database table.

However, if you attempt to depart a package that already has been departed, SQLAlchemy will return an integrity error as you can't place duplicate orders into the database.

That's when the dictionary above is returned with a False status and list of the failed packages.

I say all of that to say, the $scope.failedPkgs will only show the updated values AFTER you reload the screen.

So my question is, how do I get angular to instantly update the $scope.failedPkgs without having to reload the page? Or must you reload everytime?

**** UPDATE ****

When I console the res.data.excludedPkgs in the POST requests, it does show the updated value instantly, but the controller doesn't see the value til a reload:

```
departedFromPackages: function(ids, user_id){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: urlBase + 'depart/pkg/',
          data: {'order_id': ids, 'user': user_id}
        }).then(function(res){
         if (res.data.success == false) {
            console.log(res.data.excludedPkgs)
            $storage.failedPkgs = res.data.excludedPkgs;
            console.log($storage.failedPkgs)
         }

        });
      }

[1222822, 1222826, 1222819]
```

**** UPDATE ****

This is the function that is returning the $storage.failedPkgs

```
getFailedPkgs: function(){
        return $storage.failedPkgs;
      },
```

**** UPDATE ****

This is the function that is called via the onClick event for the departed button:

```
$scope.departed = function() {
            var selectedRows = [];
            $('.select-row-cb').each(function(){
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    selectedRows.push($(this).val());
                }
            });

            if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
                showProgressDialogueBox('Departing Package');
                if (selectedRows.length == $scope.dataTable.data().length) {
                    // All packages in wave are selected; Generate the entire wave
                    $scope.allPkgDeparted = 1
                    dataFactory.departedFromWaves($scope.waveid, $scope.user);
                } else {
                    dataFactory.departedFromPackages(selectedRows, $scope.user);
                 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you doing any view change after user clicks the depart button?

Comment: Not yet. Once I can get the value updating instantly, I will use the $scope.failedPkgs to display a popup box that shows the pkgs failed

Comment: then i haven't fully understood the issue. can you pls explain this part of the question.. `will only show the updated values AFTER you click back in the browser and then go back to the page`

Comment: Apologies. What I meant was, if you reload the page, you will see the updated $scope.failedPkgs value via the console. It's not an instant update to $scope.failedPkgs.

Comment: you try adding a `console.log(res.data.excludedPkgs)` in the $http post inside the if statement to verify if the value in $storage is getting updated at the time of post. if that is updating, you can write some more code to update the value in the controller `$scope` variable named `failedPkgs` from the `$storage. failedPkgs`..

Comment: @redflar3 I've updated the question to show the console of the POST results and it does show the updated values instantly, but the controller itself still isn't seeing it until the page is reloaded

Comment: $storage.failedPkgs is different from $scope.failedPkgs.. you have to manually fetch the value from $storage to $scope using the code inside controller (after the post)... i'm not sure how you are doing that, is that using getFailedPkgs()? if so that function wont bind the two values, try calling the same function again...

Comment: I've updated my question. Yes, dataFactory.getFailedPkgs() is what returns $storage.failedPkgs(). You're saying call it twice? If so, I'm not sure where as even if I call it after the POST, I still have to click the departed button twice to see the updated value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97223/discussion-between-redflar3-and-jimmy).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:
[reference](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply())

> AngularJS provides wrappers for common native JS async behaviors:
>
> Events => ng-click 
>   Timeouts => $timeout 
>  **jQuery.ajax() => $http**

just execute like: 
`$scope.$apply()` when you finish updating `$scope`. 
 ps: works for `$rootscope` too.

**EDIT:**

Prevent error `$digest` already in progress when calling `$scope.$apply()`

You can check if a `$digest` is already in progress by checking `$scope.$$phase`.

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  //$digest or $apply
}
```

`$scope.$$phase`  will return "$digest" or "$apply" if a  `$digest` or `$apply` is in progress.

- `$$phase` is private to the framework and there are good reasons for that.
- `$scope.$apply(callback)` invokes, among other things, `$rootScope.$digest`, which means it will redigest the root scope of the application and all of its children, even if you're within an isolated scope.
- `$scope.$digest()` will simply sync its model to the view, but will not digest its parents scope, which can save a lot of performances when working on an isolated part of your HTML with an isolated scope (from a directive mostly). `$digest` does not take a callback: you execute the code, then digest.

**EDIT:**
You can call this every time you update the `$scope` or the variables:

```
departedFromPackages: function(ids, user_id){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: urlBase + 'depart/pkg/',
          data: {'order_id': ids, 'user': user_id}
        }).then(function(res){
         if (res.data.success == false) {
            console.log(res.data.excludedPkgs)
            $storage.failedPkgs = res.data.excludedPkgs;
          // ===========>
            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
              //$digest or $apply 
            }
         //<========
            console.log($storage.failedPkgs)
         }

        });
      }
```

Comment: The issue with this is that $scope.$apply() throws Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: where are you saying call this? In my onClick function?

Comment: you can call every time you think you need to update the variables of $scope.

Comment: The issue here is that the $scope isn't injected into the dataFactory. The controller is what has access to the $scope. So when I run your update, I receive: ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below pattern solves your issue.

```
$scope.failedPkgs = dataFactory.getFailedPkgs();  // Initial call

$scope.buttonListener = buttonListener;

function buttonListener(){      // Executed on button click

    dataFactory.departedFromPackages().then(function(){
        $scope.failedPkgs = dataFactory.getFailedPkgs();
    });
}
```

In the same button listener function itself, we are calling the method to update the `$scope.failedPkgs` after the POST. In this way you don't have to click the button again. You may have to put the code in the then block, since factory call for the POST returns a promise and is not resolved at the instant, so if you immediately call the `getFailedPkgs()`, there won't be any value in `$storage.failedPkgs`, since $http might not have returned the promise.

Comment: Only issue with this is that I receive: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Howdie do,

So I decided to look at this from a different perspective. Instead of using the dataFactory.getFailedPkgs(), I instead just issue a broadcast via the rootScope and issue catch it in my controller:

DataFactory:

```
departedFromPackages: function(ids, user_id){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: urlBase + 'depart/pkg/',
          data: {'order_id': ids, 'user': user_id}
        }).then(function(res){
         if (res.data.success == false) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('failedPackages', {packages: res.data.excludedPkgs});
         }

        });
      },
```

Packages Controller:

```
$scope.$on('failedPackages', function(event, args){
        console.log(event)
        console.log(args)
    });
```

This allows me to see the failed packages INSTANTLY. Thank you EVERYONE for your assistance